# VBA mirror areas update on change

Tags: excel, onchange, vba

I have to areas in an Excel sheet that I need for them to get updated if there is a change in either of the area with the same value. See example of areas with example values:

[image]

The code that I tried is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Area1 As Range
    Dim Area2 As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set Area1 = Range("B3:B9")
    Set Area2 = Range("D3:D9")

    If Not Application.Intersect(Area1, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
        Range("D" & Target.Row) = Target.Value
    End If

    If Not Application.Intersect(Area2, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
        Range("B" & Target.Row) = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error. I believe because when I write in Area 1 or 2 the code update the other area, but as a change is detected, then tries to change the initial area. Therefore, the code is getting in an endless loop.

Any ideas on how I can sort this issue?

What I'm trying to achieve is that what ever section the user updates, it will be replicated in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `Range(Target.Address)` doesn't make much sense `Target` is already a range so you convert a range into an address into a range. Just use `Target` directly.

The issue here is that if you change a cell within `Worksheet_Change` event this triggers another `Worksheet_Change` event, which triggers another and …

So you need to `Application.EnableEvents = False` before the change and `Application.EnableEvents = True` afterwards.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Area1 As Range
    Dim Area2 As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set Area1 = Range("B3:B9")
    Set Area2 = Range("D3:D9")

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Application.Intersect(Area1, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Range("D" & Target.Row) = Target.Value
    End If

    If Not Application.Intersect(Area2, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Range("B" & Target.Row) = Target.Value
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Peh. Fantastic!!